# Что будет являться грамматической основой?

Tags: синтаксис

**Единственный способ сделать утро хорошим — проспать его.**

Answer (score 2):

Я, честно говоря, не знаю, чему сейчас в школе учат, но навскидку: 
"Способ" - подлежащее, "сделать" - дополнение, выраженное инфинитивом.
"проспать его" - составное сказуемое, возможно с опущенной связкой.   
Если это принять за истину, остальное с очевидностью вытекает.

Comment: Не соглашусь, что способ - подлежащее. Задайте вопрос: что является чем? Проспать является единственным способом сделать утро хорошим. Изменить падеж с именительного на творительный в данной ситуации может только сказуемое (составное именное). Насчет дополнения соглашусь. Соответственно сказуемое - способ.

Comment: Единственный способ - это проспать. Очевидно, что "способ" - подлежащее.

Comment: > Задайте вопрос: что является чем? Проспать является единственным способом сделать утро хорошим.

Не катит. "Сократ - смертный". Кем является смертый? Сократом.

Comment: Кто является кем? Сократ является смертным.

Comment: Ну тогда и "способ... является... проспать"  
Замена глагола-связки на является некорректна уже потому, что "является" управляет творительным падежом.

"Бегемот есть гиппопотам". Чем явялется бегемот? Гиппопотамом. Чем является гиппопотам? Бегемотом. Подлежащего в предложении нет?

Comment: Полностью согласен с @behemothus
Если бы "проспать" являлось подлежащим, тире не ставилось бы, так как появился бы обратный порядок слов.

Comment: Замена глагола-связки как раз является способом проверки для составного именного сказуемого. Подлежащее не меняет падеж при такой замене, остается в форме именительного. А вот имя в именном сказуемом при такой замене может изменить форму с именительного на творительный. Такие конструкции синонимичны. Смысл предложения не меняется при некотором изменении грамматических характеристик членов предложения.

Comment: > Замена глагола-связки как раз является способом проверки для составного именного сказуемого

Вряд ли именно такая. "Есть" на "является". Во всяком случае здесь она явно неуместна.

Comment: По поводу запятой: тире между подлежащим и сказуемым ставится, если один из главных членов предложения выражен неопределенной формой глагола, а другой - существительным в И.п. Вот пример из пособия для поступающих в вузы: Стремиться вперед - цель жизни. Стремиться - подлежащее, цель - сказуемое. Аналогичный пример.

Comment: Определяет возможность такой замены грамматика, синтаксис, никак не семантика.  

Дальнейшее - не понял вообще. К чему тут эти банальности?

Comment: Я как-то тоже потерял нить логики. @olsa, при обратном порядке подлежащего и сказуемого в случае с инфинитивами и сущ. в И.п. тире не ставится. "Вся Россия наш сад" (Чехов). Сад - подлежащее, Россия - сказуемое. Тире отсутствует. При вашем варианте подлежащего и сказуемого тире пропадает.

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что при определении грамматической основы способ перестановки недопустим. получается другое предложение, иногда совершенно другое: Хорошее утро - односоставное, утро хорошее - двусоставное. Несмотря на минус у Виктора, в его ответе есть рациональное зерно. Только я бы все-таки центром высказывания, подлежащим определила (как и behemothus) слово "способ". Какой  способ сделать утро хорошим? Сказуемое - проспать. Только почему все определяют "сделать" как дополнение? Способ  какой? Сделать - это определение.

Comment: Я весьма тронут Вашей деликатностью

Comment: Лара, Вы умница!

Comment: Катюша, я так рада, что Вы снова с нами! Вас долго не было...

Comment: )))Спасибо! В С-П летала. И я очень рада. Без форума и без вас уже и жизнь не жизнь...

Answer (score 0):

Подлежащее - проспать. Сказуемое - способ. Проверим: *Проспать есть хороший способ сделать утро хорошим*. Что есть что? Имеем составное именное сказуемое. Подлежащее выражено инфинитивом.

Answer (score 0):

"Способ" - подлежащее, выраженное сущ. в И.п. "Проспать" - сказуемое, выраженное инфинитивом. Отсюда и возникает тире между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Comment: Два подлежащих? И между ними тире? :-)

Comment: Извините, ошибка. "Проспать", конечно, сказуемое.

Answer (score 0):

Вы уж меня извините, но из школьной теории я запомнила следующее: если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит тире, то подлежащее всегда стоит слева от тире, а сказуемое всегда справа. Кстати, практика всегда подтверждает это простейшее правило.
Я абсолютно согласна с Lapf, что при определении грамматической основы способ перестановки недопустим, потому что меняется смысл высказывания. Например: дважды два - четыре (здесь подлежащее - дважды два, а сказуемое - четыре); поменяйте подлежащее со сказуемым местами, и изменятся синтаксические роли: подлежащим будет четыре, а сказуемым - дважды два. Четыре - это дважды два)
А "сделать" - это несогласованное определение, способ - какой? сделать.

Answer (score -2):

Подлежащее обозначает предмет речевого высказывания, т.е. о чем говорится в предложении. О чем говорится в данном предложении? О "проспать".Это подлежащее. Что говорится о подлежащем "проспать"? - "Сделать хорошим". Так в детстве я определил бы здесь грамматическую основу предложения, да и сейчас поступаю аналогичным способом.